# JSF2 ViewStateID can be re-used?

Tags: jsf-2

We have a JSF2.1.7 application ,our IT security found an issue as below

```
 In Browser:
    1) Get login Page.
    2) Post Login Page with UserName/Password & submit&JSFViewStateId_1&JSessionID_1
    3)Successful login.
```

Within minutes , if we make the same http request as below with old ViewState and new JSession.

```
1) Post Login page with UserName/Password & submit&JSFViewStateId_1&JSessionID_2
   2) Successful Login
```

Wondering ,how the old view state is accepted by the server ,when the second request is made ,should it not report view expired?
Does the server validate the ViewSTate and JSession ID as the combined authentication.

Answer (score 0):

That's only possible if the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is set to `client`. The `javax.faces.ViewState` does then not represent the unique view state identifier referencing a view state which is stored in the user session, but it represents instead the whole view state itself, in serialized flavor. The session ID is then not relevant anymore.

The webapp being tested has apparently client side state saving enabled. Whether that's a security problem is a second. It would only be possible to extract and send the view state to a malicious server when there's a XSS hole. JSF has by itself very strong builtin XSS prevention which the developer can only disable by explicitly using `escape="false"` while redisplaying user-controlled data. Even *if* there was a XSS hole, then it would *also* be possible to send the session ID along. It wouldn't have been more secure with server side state saving.

Comment: We do not have avax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to client .The view state is getting issued differently for every request .  The only issues is that,can that view state be used with different JSession ID. Where escape=false be set ,in faces-config.xml>

Comment: Then there's a misinterpretation during testing.